# awk array is created but elements are missing

Tags: awk, unix-text-processing

I have this sample file

```
userX   2020    start   id1
userY   2005    stop    id2
userZ   2006    start   id3
userT   2014    stop    id1
userX   2010    stop    id1
```

I want to create an array where year value `$2` is element for every unique user-id pair `$1$4` with given condition `$3=="stop"`. For example `arr[userXid1]=2010` and `arr[userTid1]=2014`

my code:

```
awk '{if($3=="stop") arr[$1$4]=$2} END{print arr[userXid1]}' log
```

expected output:

```
2010
```

But **this prints empty line**. when I `print length(arr)` it gives `3` which makes sense. but `$2` values are not there and I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

---

```
awk '{if($3=="start") arrstart[$1,$4]=$2; else if($3=="stop") arrstop[$1,$4]=$2 fi; next} END{for(i in arrstop) if(arrstart[i]>arrstop[i]) print i}' SUBSEP=':' log
```

addition: final code, nothing to do with question.

Comment: Change your `END` part to `END{for(i in arr) print i,arr[i]}`. The keys and values are in `arr[]` but you need to reference them by quoting constants, for example like `print arr["userXid1"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '$3 == "stop" {arr[$1,$4] = $2} END {print arr["userX","id1"]}' file

2010
```

To print all unique values use:

```sh
awk '$3 == "stop" {arr[$1,$4] = $2}
END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' SUBSEP=':' file

userY:id2 2005
userT:id1 2014
userX:id1 2010
```

Comment: Thanks. one little extra: would `END` block properly run if be like this? `END{for (i=1;i<=length(arr);i++) if(arr[$1,$4]<$2 && $3=="start") print $0}'` in order to compare with `start` time for every unique user-id pair?

Comment: Since we have `$3 == "stop"` we are not storing `start` values in our array.

Comment: I created another array for `start` and compared them successfully, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `tac` + `awk` combination you could try following to get only very last unique combination(s) of 1st, 4th field's value.

```
tac Input_file | awk '!arr[$1,$4]++ && $3=="stop"{print $2;exit}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, reverse the Input_file by `tac` first and then pass it as an standard input to `awk` program as input, in `awk` program print very first unique combination of $1,$4 then print 2nd field of that line and come out of the program immediately by `exit`.

***OR*** you want to specifically look for keys `id1` and `userX` respectively in 4th and 1st fields(with their last value only) then try following.

```
tac file1 | awk '$1=="userX" && $4=="id1" && $3=="stop"{print $2;exit}'
```